# Need an object to rotate from current position to new position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I would like a GameObject to rotate from it's current position to 0,0,0 when that event trigger is called.

I've updated my code, this does works and does what I want but is it possible to add a 'speed' variable to control the speed at which it rotates back to 0,0,0 after Quaternion.identity?

many thanks

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class rotate : MonoBehaviour
{

public GameObject spinme;
public float speed;

public void spin()

{
        spinme.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
}
```

}

Comment: So you want it to face the default direction, or do you want it to move to 0,0,0?

Comment: rotate to 0,0,0

Comment: do you want rotation or just to snap to 0,0,0?

Comment: rotate does just that, it rotates  it doesnt look like you read the unity docs much.. as "rotation" holds the current amount of rotation.. perhaps you can start with that

Comment: `currentposition(0,0,0)` makes no sense ..also .. are you talking about a rotation or a position .. those are two different things and make no sense how you are using those names..

Comment: apologies I'm new to this, and it's a bit of a struggle. I've updated my code, this does works and does what I want but is it possible to add a variable to control the speed at which it rotates back to 0,0,0? many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a quaternion gradually to an object (in as many steps as you want) so that it changes according to a velocity or time.

That is known as interpolation. For quaternions the interpolation formula is known as SLERP:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp

Investigate how it works in unity3d.